# Logs not getting created in Django Project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, logging

My Django project is not creating logs, this is the Logging info in my setting.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
     'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
     'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/home/bithu/bservice/bservice/logs/djangoLog.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},}
```

`and this is how I call it from my views.py:`

`import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse`

`def test_view(request):
    #return 'OK'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger.info('checking')
    logger.info('checking')
    return HttpResponse('Testing  Web Service.......')`

I have created the log files manually and given it 777 permission still the logs are not getting created .

Can somebody shed some light on it please.

Comment: I have got the issue with this settings , I have added the logger for my app , and I have resolved it by adding the same to the settings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
# rest of config
'loggers': {
'your_app_name': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'propagate': True,
   },
},}
```